# Split string repeat Tcl

Tags: string, tcl

I am a fresh learner of Tcl and I faced an issue of understanding this whole concept:

```
<name of variable> set [split "[string repeat "-,-," [columns]]-",]
```

columns is a variable with value 6;
How the split will be and which is my whole string?

Thank you all

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to ask, but have you tried running that piece of code?

Comment: What actual input data do you have? What output do you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
<name of variable> set [split "[string repeat "-,-," [columns]]-",]
```

You have to unpack Tcl commands from the inside out because the inner-most nested brackets are executed first.

- `columns` is a **proc** that, hopefully, returns an integer.
- then `string repeat` repeats "-,-," that many times.
- then the double quoted string adds a trailing `-`
- then `split` **should** split that "-,-,-,...-" string on commas resulting in *a list of "2 * columns + 1" hyphens*.

**Except**:

- there is a missing space before the last comma in the split command
- the `set` command looks like: `set varname value` (unless you're dealing with an object)

```
set <name of variable> [split "[string repeat "-,-," [columns]]-" ,]
# ...............................................................^
```

---

Demonstrating:

```
set columns 6
proc columns {} {return $::columns}
set result [split "[string repeat "-,-," [columns]]-" ,]
puts $result
puts [llength $result] ;# should be 13
```

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - -
13
```

---

You could achieve the same result with:

```
set result [lrepeat [expr {2 * [columns] + 1}] "-"]
```

---

Tcl is actually a very simple language. The entire syntax only has 12 rules: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm

Comment: Seems sensible this way, thank you all for the help!